# PHP Composer Installation on OS Catalina

Tags: composer-php, macos-catalina

Just tried to install composer on my new Macbook Pro. Ran into an issue when I tried to install it globally. I'm not sure if this operating system related or not.

**My Steps**

1. `sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
2. `sudo php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`
3. `sudo php composer-setup.php`
4. `sudo php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
5. `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

**Problem**

I can run composer if I access it directly. `php composer.phar` works just fine. But I can't get it to work globally by moving it to the `/usr/local/bin/composer` directory.

**Question**

Is this operating system related? And if you could shed anymore light onto the issue that would be great.

Comment: sudo is not advised or required for all but the moving of the composer.phar to /usr/sbin... For install instructions: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not operating system related.

In this case, I made the mistake of moving `composer.phar` into a folder named composer. So the structure was this: `/usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar`. The correct approach is to rename `composer.phar` to `composer`, making the structure `/usr/local/bin/composer`.

Answer (score 1):

> To get it working globally, create the the bin directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

After that, simply move it to the directory you created.

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```